# How do I pivot XML nodes to XML rows?

Tags: map-force

I have an XML file which has hard-coded element names such as FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME etc.

```
<employee>
  <EMP_NO>1234</EMP_NO>
  <FIRST_NAME>Bob</FIRST_NAME>
  <SOMETHING_ELSE>Weakly mapped</SOMETHING_ELSE>
  <SOME_OTHER_VALUE>Also weakly mapped</SOME_OTHER_VALUE>
  <LAST_NAME>Smith</LAST_NAME>
</employee>
```

The output I am after is

```
<employee>
  <number>123</number>
  <values>
    <value>
      <name>FIRST_NAME</name>
      <value>Bob</value>
    </value>
    <value>
      <name>LAST_NAME</name>
      <value>Smith</value>
    </value>
    <value>
      <name>SOMETHING_ELSE</name>
      <value>Weakly mapped</value>
    </value>
    <value>
      <name>SOME_OTHER_VALUE</name>
      <value>Also weakly mapped</value>
    </value>
  </value>
</employee>
```

Some of these nodes are expected, **emp_no**, **first_name** and **last_name** and I will create explicit mapping from the XML source to the XML dest for those nodes to match the input.

What I need to achieve next is for every unmapped node to also add items to my target XML. If a new node comes in then it will also be added to the target XML.

If this is not possible then I'd just like a quick way of manually selecting nodes and transforming them into items, otherwise I am going to have to spend hours manually adding  nodes in the target and wiring up the name (constant) and value from the source node.

This is the kind of thing I am having to do now...

[image: Manual approach]

Obviously for hundreds of nodes this is going to take me hours, and I have a number of files to create mappings for so it will take me days. I'd really like at least to be able to do something like this...

[image: Desired approach]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do what you want in MapForce with a custom, imported inline xsl template, and a slight modification to your range schema.  It is a bit of a hack to do this in MapForce, and it is probably easier and cleaner to use a hand-written xsl transform instead.

Start with the custom template (in a file, e.g. custom.xsl):

```
<xsl:template name="metaItemIterate">
    <xsl:param name="employeeNode"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$employeeNode/*">
        <xsl:element name="metaItem">
            <xsl:element name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

*Note that this template generates a single element with multiple children.  You could alternatively just generate the necessary child elements, and link them accordingly...*

Then use the <kbd>Add/Remove Libraries...</kbd> button (found below the Libraries) to add your xsl file as a library.

Drag the new function between the range and domain schemas, and connect the `employee` node to `employeeNode` and the `result` of the function to `clientDefinedMetaData`.

[image: example of mapping with custom function between schemas]

*Note you may need to add the attribute `mixed="true"` to the schema definition for clientDefinedMetaData in order to allow generation of random elements below it.*

The output I get with your data from clicking the <kbd>Output</kbd> tab:

[image: example of output as generated from MapForce]

Also, if you cannot change the schema definition to allow the mixed elements below it, it is probably not possible to go about this any other way with MapForce.

Comment: If you need to pick and choose certain elements, you can add that code to the called template, e.g. if node has a value, generate the element.